# Is it possible to push an video stream via OBS to a video server for consumption by another OBS Studio?

Tags: video, streaming, obs

Just wanted whether this was possible.

I know that within OBS, I can stream video from my phone camera on a url like localhost:5050 when I used a "turn phone into webcam" app.

So I was wondering, it is possible for OBS Studio in one location to be able to push a video stream to a remote server, in which another OBS Studio in another location can consumer via the said OBS Browser source input?

If so what is this setup called and what should I look into?

I hope I have been understood. I have noone around me who dabs within this field.

Comment: I've heard from some people that they've pushed an OBS recording to XSplit which then only streams the image - so I would imagine that it is possible to push one OBS stream into another instance. How, I don't know though.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you want, i can write an answer